# Database Seeder not inserting correct data in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite, eloquent

I need to seed Reg-Ex patterns in SqLite database. I'm using Laravel 7.
Here is my seeder:

```
<?php
use App\PhoneValidetionRules;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PhoneValidetionRulesSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
    $rules = '
    {
        "iPhone": "\\biPhone\\b|\\biPod\\b",
        "BlackBerry": "BlackBerry|\\bBB10\\b|rim[0-9]+|\\b(BBA100|BBB100|BBD100|BBE100|BBF100|STH100)\\b-[0-9]+",
        "HTC": "HTC|HTC.*(Sensation|Evo|Vision|Explorer|6800|8100|8900|A7272|S510e|C110e|Legend|Desire|T8282)|APX515CKT|Qtek9090|APA9292KT|HD_mini|Sensation.*Z710e|PG86100|Z715e|Desire.*(A8181|HD)|ADR6200|ADR6400L|ADR6425|001HT|Inspire 4G|Android.*\\bEVO\\b|T-Mobile G1|Z520m|Android [0-9.]+; Pixel",
        "Nexus": "Nexus One|Nexus S|Galaxy.*Nexus|Android.*Nexus.*Mobile|Nexus 4|Nexus 5|Nexus 6"
    }';
    $data = [];
    foreach (json_decode($rules, true) as $key=>$value){
        $data[] = [
            'name' => $key,
            'regex' => $value
        ];
    }
    PhoneValidetionRules::insert($data);
}
}
```

When I seed it, all `\b`are converted to `\x08`. Here is database:

[image]

Here is table blueprint:

```
Schema::create('phone_validetion_rules', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('regex');
    });
```

If I update regex from PhpStorm manually, It insert correctly.
How can I insert Reg-Ex to database using Laravel Seeder?

Answer (score 1):

Why not inserting them with `json_encode()` like so

```
'regex' => json_encode($value)
```

the data will inserted like `"\biPhone\b|\biPod\b"` if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Upvote for  a nice trick. But it is not the answer i need. why  it converts `\b` are converted to `\x08` ? And what is the exact method to upload Reg-Ex to database using larael Model? Raw Sql can do this also. But I don't want to write raw Sql in my project.

Comment: This doesn't work. for `json_decode(PhoneValidetionRules::find(5)->regex)` output is `iPhone|iPod` with `print_f` or `"\x08iPhone\x08|\x08iPod\x08"` with `dd`

Comment: First, you don't need `json_decode(PhoneValidetionRules::find(5)->regex)` to get regex value you can do `PhoneValidetionRules::find(5)->regex` the output will be `"\biPhone\b|\biPod\b"` to remove extra `"` you can do `str_replace("\"", "", PhoneValidetionRules::find(5)->regex)` and you will get `\biPhone\b|\biPod\b"`.

Comment: Second, why `\b` converted to `\x08` because this is the `json_decode()` behavior it converts some special characters to unicode  and you have to avoid those special character in your string, you read more here https://www.json.org/json-en.html